# Is there a way to know, whether a route event DID NOT occur in angular 2?

Tags: angular, events, angular2-routing

Inside a block of code, I have to conditionally run few statements when a router event occurs, and when a router event does not occur. 
I tried using the `closed` property of the router subscription variable. That doesn't come useful. I was wondering If I can detect If there was no router event, because the code to run if NO ROUTER event is synchronous and that runs even when the route changes(because this is asynchronous and little delayed).

```
.catch((error: any) => {
        if (this.routerSubscription)
            this.routerSubscription.unsubscribe();
        this.routerSubscription =  this._router.events.subscribe(
            (event) => {
                if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
                   // code if router event occurs
                    this.routerSubscription.unsubscribe();
                }
            }
        );

        // code if no router event occurs
      return  Observable.throw(error);
  });
```

Comment: Sounds weird. What does "no router event mean"? Application running since 1h and still no router event, or better 5h ?  ;-)

Comment: I have  edited the question, so, when I get an exception, and enter the catch block, I need to know, that when the exception occured whether a router event was occured or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a flag in case a router event happened, and in the complete callback, check whether one has happened:

```ts
    bool wasEvent = false;
    this.routerSubscription =  this._router.events
        .filter(e => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
        .first() // take only one
        .subscribe(
          event => wasEvent = true,
          (err) => {},
          () => console.log(`Router events happened: ${wasEvents}`)
        );            
    );
```

Comment: With my scarce understanding of callbacks, What I inferred of the answer: (not considering filters now) inside subscribe `.subscribe( (event) => { set flag here, and code for when route changes }, (noEvent) => { this will run, if event doesn't happen and I can check the flag here } )` . If this is true, it never goes to the `(noEvent) part`

Comment: There is no value passed for the complete callback AFAIR, therefore `(noEvent)` should be `()`. If you don't use `filter` and `first`, then the complete callback will not be called before you navigate away from the current route.

Comment: I am missing something here, when I use `filter` and `first`, none of the codes within `event` and `()` work. Tested on 1. when the control reaches the catch block on a route change 2. without a route change.

Comment: Sorry, mixed something up. Complete is the 3rd callback, not the 2nd. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I tried that, but no, I think I am missing something in `filter` and `first` after adding them, none of the codes inside `event`, `err` or `()` run

Comment: Perhaps there are no `NavigationEnd` events, but the 3rd callback should still be called. Sorry, don't know how I should tell from here without seeing what's going on in your application.

Comment: No, Thank you for the suggestions, I will try to figure a way out.

Comment: Just one thing I wanted to know, even if there in no route change, the complete callback should be called?

Comment: I guess only when you navigate away from the route, this is when the observable should be closed by the router. Otherwise there is no way of knowing if there will eventually come an event.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135835/discussion-between-ashish-ranjan-and-gunter-zochbauer).